# Revit Model Data Extraction

Tags: revit-api, revit, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, pyrevit

I want to have an excel file of all the geometries with their dimensions present in Revit model (like doors, windows with their quantities and dimensions). How can I get that? Can I use Model derivative API for that? Or any other possible way?

Comment: I also need an answer for this, did you find out the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

Check out Augusto's new sample `viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet`:

- [Test run](https://autodesk-forge.github.io/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet/)
- [GitHub source repo](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet)

Comment: How to add reference and where? How to call downloadxlsx method? I have to use Postman or any other? I have used model derivative API for data and geometry extraction. But I am unable to understand the procedure explained in those links. Please explain it detail.

Comment: please post your question as an issue directly on the github repo.